# I am going through Automate The Boring Stuff with Python and I'm stuck on an activity :- Read the emphasized text to read the activity

Tags: python

### Quoted Heading

This is the exercise:-

> "Coin Flip Streaks For this exercise, we’ll try doing an experiment. If you flip a coin 100 times and write down an “H” for each heads and “T” for each tails, you’ll create a list that looks like “T T T T H H H H T T.” If you ask a human to make up 100 random coin flips, you’ll probably end up with alternating head-tail results like “H T H T H H T H T T,” which looks random (to humans), but isn’t mathematically random. A human will almost never write down a streak of six heads or six tails in a row, even though it is highly likely to happen in truly random coin flips. Humans are predictably bad at being random.

> Write a program to find out how often a streak of six heads or a streak of six tails comes up in a randomly generated list of heads and tails. Your program breaks up the experiment into two parts: the first part generates a list of randomly selected 'heads' and 'tails' values, and the second part checks if there is a streak in it. Put all of this code in a loop that repeats the experiment 10,000 times so we can find out what percentage of the coin flips contains a streak of six heads or tails in a row. As a hint, the function call random.randint(0, 1) will return a 0 value 50% of the time and a 1 value the other 50% of the time."

```
import random
numI = 0
numII = 0
numberOfStreaks = 0
tHlists = []
for experimentNumber in range(10000):
    for i in range(100):
        if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
            tHlists.append('T')
            numII = 0
            numI += 1
            if numI == 6:
                numberOfStreaks += 1
                numI =0
        else:
            tHlists.append('H')
            numI = 0
            numII += 1
            if numII == 6:
                numberOfStreaks += 1
                numII = 0
        
    
print('Chance of streak: %s%%' % (numberOfStreaks / 100))
```

**strong text**

> Please find the mistake in this the code works but the output is on average 159.XX% which does not seem right

Comment: Why do you say that "programmers are notoriously bad at math"?

Comment: The exercise seems to be asking for the chance of 1 or more streak within 100 coin tosses. But you are summing all of the streaks, on average getting 1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to reset the number of heads and tails found to zero at the start of each experiment.  Second, the exercise seems to be asking for the % of experiments which have 1 or more streak, whereas you are currently calculating the total number of streaks. The adjusted code below illustrates this.

```
total_streaks = 0
experiments_with_streak = 0
for experimentNumber in range(10000):
    tails = 0
    heads = 0
    streaks = 0
    for i in range(100):
        if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
            heads = 0
            tails += 1
            if tails == 6:
                streaks += 1
                tails =0
        else:
            tails = 0
            heads += 1
            if heads == 6:
                streaks += 1
                heads = 0
    print("Streaks in experiment number", experimentNumber, ":", streaks)
    total_streaks += streaks
    if streaks > 0:
        experiments_with_streak += 1
    
print("Average number of streaks per experiment", total_streaks / 10000) # about 1.5
print('Chance of streak: %s%%' % (experiments_with_streak / 100)) # about 80%
```

One more concise way of doing this would be by building a string of Ts and Hs for each experiment.

```
streaks = 0
for experiment_number in range(10000):
    tosses = "".join(random.choice("TH") for _ in range(100))
    if "TTTTTT" in tosses or "HHHHHH" in tosses:
        streaks += 1
print(f"Chance of streak: {streaks / 100}%")
```